# Converting an ASP.NET application into a SharePoint application, need assistance on doubts and good practice

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, deployment, sharepoint-server, user-controls

we have a ASP.NET simple application with custom functionality that performs certain calculations based on data entered in text box and shows output in a label.

We would now like to use it in SharePoint. I have done some research and am having some confusion with foll. doubts in my mind..

1)  We are confused whether to create a webpart of this functionality or do we create an user control? or is there any other way?

2)  I would like to know on what circumstances does this decision depend?

3)  If we create a webpart, then, is the only way to add it to page be from front end (that is, edit page--> add webpart-->save page) or is there any other method (VS or Designer?)?

4)  Is the only way to add an UserControl to use SharePoint designer (Create site page--> edit site page --> register and add usercontrol tag?) or is there another way to use an UserControl on SharePoint page (VS or GUI?)?

5) How to deploy incase we are using webpart method and how to deploy incase we use UserControl method?

Please guide me on this. It would help me more if you provide answers to my points. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deciding whether to use Visual Web Part or a User Control, there is already a very nice thread on SharePoint Stack Exchange:

[web parts vs user controls](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12089/web-parts-vs-user-controls)

About deployment on SharePoint from Visual Studio, well most of the times (in our environment - may not be feasible with you), we add a Page Layout and deploy it using Visual Studio..

The Page Layout contains the markup for User Control/Visual Web Part (Register dll at the top etc).. and once you have the page layout, you can programmatically create a new page based on that Page Layout and yes the new page now contains your user control/ web part.

If there are any other methods, I would love to know too :)